# how to get the correct output format

Tags: xml, xquery

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $letter := ("A","B")
let $number := (1,2,3)

for $i in $letter

for $j in $number
return ($i,$j)
```

How can I get the output format will be.  Thanks

```
A
    1
    2
    3
    
B
    1
    2
    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to have the indentation and carriage returns in the output:

```
let $letter := ("A","B")
let $number := (1,2,3)

for $i in $letter
let $line := (
   $i,
   for $j in $number
   return "    "||$j
 )
 string-join($line, "&#13;")
```

More concisely, using [simple map operator `!`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator) instead of for loops:

```
let $letter := ("A","B")
let $number := (1,2,3)
return
 string-join($letter ! (., $number ! ("    "||.)), "&#13;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for $i in $letter
return ($i,$number)
```

or

```
for $i in $letter
return ($i,
for $j in $number
return $j)
```

Output (formatting aside):

```
A
1
2
3

B
1
2
3
```

Comment: Or more simply in 3.1, `$letter ! (., $number)`